Controlling 12V DC Motor speed via Positive Wire
I'm working on a custom-built buggy and need to slow down the 12v DC fuel pump motor by approx 20%. I've tried three different PWM speed controllers, but they all interrupt the negative wire. In my vehicle, the motor gets its negative from the chassis, so there's no negative wire to insert the controller into.
What are some solutions for controlling the pump motor speed in this setup? Would a PWM generator and solid state relay work? Any advice or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated!

This is really an automotive question ask in cars.  but have you considered the plumbing approach. add a constriction or bypass in the pipes.

What about using an adjustable DC/DC converter?

If I read your question correctly you're on the wrong track. The fuel pump has very little to do with engine speed. Its job is to provide fuel to whatever does, which could be a carburetor or injectors. And neither of those two choices is a good one for speed control.

It would be helpful to know why you need to lower the pump speed by 20%.  If the max demand is 80% of what the pump can provide then that sounds about right

Hi Frog. It's a custom buggy. Unfortunately limited options meant that the closest pump I could find is over powered and needs to be slowed down to prevent the fuel system from being over loaded. 20% is just an estimate. When I fit the speed controller I will use a fuel monitoring system to set the correct output.
